# In Unity, how does Unity magically call all "Interfaces"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface

Unity has an "interface":

`IPointerDownHandler` ([doco](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html))

You simply implement [OnPointerDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.OnPointerDown.html) ...

```
public class Whoa:MonoBehaviour,IPointerDownHandler
    {
    public void OnPointerDown (PointerEventData data)
        { Debug.Log("whoa!"); }
    }
```

and Unity will "magically" call the `OnPointerDown` in any such MonoBehavior.

**You do NOT have to register them, set an event, nor do anything else**.

All you do syntactically is add "IPointerDownHandler" and "public void OnPointerDown" to a class, and you can get those messages magically.

(If you're not a Unity dev - it even works if you suddenly add one in the Editor while the game is running!)

## How the hell do they do that, and how can I do it?

So, I want to do this:

```
public interface IGetNews
 {
 void SomeNews(string s);
 }
```

and then I can add `SomeNews` *to any MonoBehavior*.

## The alternate solutions are obvious, I want to know specifically how Unity achieve that "magic" behavior.

(BTW: I feel they should not have called these "interfaces", since, it's basically *nothing at all like an interface - it's sort of the opposite!* You could say they magically made a way to inherit from more than one abstract class, I guess.)

---

Aside:

if you've not used Unity before, the conventional way to do this - since we don't have access to Unity magic - is just add a UnityEvent to your daemon which will be sending the message in question:

```
public class BlahDaemon:MonoBehaviour
  {
  public UnityEvent onBlah;
  
    ...
    onBlah.Invoke();
```

Say you have classes Aaa, Bbb, Ccc which want to get the message.  Simply connect the Unity event (either by dragging in the editor or in code), example:

```
public class Aaa:MonoBehaviour
  {
  void Awake()
    {
    BlahDaemon b = Object.FindObjectOfType<BlahDaemon>();
    b.onBlah.AddListener(OnBlah);
    }
  
  public void OnBlah()
    {
    Debug.Log("almost as good as Unity's");
    }
  }
```

You're basically "registering" your call in `Awake`, you are indeed piggybacking on the magic Unity use - whatever it is.  But I want to use the magic directly.

Comment: You reopen this one for bounty but what is the question?

Comment: Hey @Everts!  Thanks again for the fantastic answer.  It's common on here to start a bounty to reward a fantastic answer.  (If you glance through my history, I often do that.)  Cheers again bud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI-dependent built-in interfaces like IPointerDownHandler, IDragHandler Etc are called by **EventsSystem** class/script [this is attached on the EventSystem GameObject that is created automatically, when you create UI/Canvas object] and only work on UI Elements [for testing if you turn off or delete the EventSystem GameObject from the scene or even disable **EventsSystem** script, these interfaces will not be called and all UI elements will stop working (functionality point-of-view, means your register functions will not be called)].

So, these interfaces methods didn't get called as magically on their own. These are called via **EventsSystem** script.

**Read About Event system:** [CLICK HERE](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/EventSystem.html)

There are 3 main components that you need to remember for interaction with the UI elements in Unity:

1. **GraphicRaycaster:** It is attached to the Canvas object itself. It is responsible for sending the raycasts to UI elements of that canvas and determines if any of them have been hit. if you remove it from the canvas, no interaction can happen with UI elements of that canvas like click, scroll Etc and these interfaces will not also call. `[LINK FOR MORE][2]`
2. **InputSystemUIInputModule:**: this is attached on EventSystem Gameobject is responsible to tell canvases in the whole Unity scene, What to consider as input for the UI and vice versa. Like what will mouse left-click on UI to consider as input to UI elements, etc.
   and It calls method link OnPointDown, OnDragStarted Etc interface related. Read More: [LINK](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/UISupport.html)
   [image]
3. **EventSystem:** it is responsible for processing and handling UI events in a whole Unity scene. It doesn't work independently and required `BaseInputModules` to work properly and it also maintains elements' status or user interactions. For Details: [LINK](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.html)

Just for understanding, consider it as a story: The EventSystem uses InputSystemUIInputModule to get input from your mouse, keyboard or touch and on the bases of these inputs, the EventSystem calls to does RayCast for whether you have interacted with any element or not (save references of that element in it) if yes then call built-in functions like hover, select, mouse down/up, drag canceled on that element based on life cycle (the mouse/touch pointed elements are stored in EventSystem.current) via InputSystemUIInputModule.

Now, if you want to call any IPointerDownHander method, maybe they do like this internally on click on the element of the UI and vice versa:
`IPointerDownHander pointerDownHander = EventSystem.Current.GetComponent<IPointerDownHander>();` //assumption for making an understanding with the interface being cast to object, if that interface is attached to object then that object will be returned and you will be able to call the interface registered method.

```
if(ipd) ipd.OnPointerDown(var etc)
```

or below code Copied from Unity UI Package, where you can learn more accurately about this execution

```
// Invoke OnPointerDown, if present.
                var newPressed = ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy(currentOverGo, eventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);
if (newPressed == null)
    newPressed = ExecuteEvents.GetEventHandler<IPointerClickHandler>(currentOverGo); //copied from the Unity UI package
```

Comment: very impressive answer!

Answer (score 29):

When it comes to XXXUpdate, OnCollisionXXX and other MonoBehaviours, the way Unity registers is not reflection as it has been widely believed but some internal compilation process.

> ### HOW UPDATE IS CALLED
>
> **No, Unity doesn’t use System.Reflection to find a magic method every time it needs to call one.**
>
> Instead, the first time a MonoBehaviour of a given type is accessed the underlying script is inspected through scripting runtime (either
>   Mono or IL2CPP) whether it has any magic methods defined and this
>   information is cached. If a MonoBehaviour has a specific method it is
>   added to a proper list, for example if a script has Update method
>   defined it is added to a list of scripts which need to be updated
>   every frame.
>
> During the game Unity just iterates through these lists and executes methods from it — that simple. Also, this is why it doesn’t matter if
>   your Update method is public or private.

http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/

In the case of an interface, I would assume it does a bit more since the interface is required. Else, you would just add the method like any other MonoBehaviour methods.

My assumption (that could be wrong), it uses a basic GetComponents on this GameObject. Then iterate the resulting array and call the method that HAS TO BE implemented since it is from the interface.

You could reproduce the pattern with:

```
NewsData data;
if(GetNews(out data))
{
    IGetNews [] getNews = data.gameObject.GetComponents<IGetNews>();
    foreach(IGetNews ign in getNews){ ign.SomeNews(); }
}
```

GetNews is a method that checks if some news should be sent to the object. You could think of it like Physics.Raycast that assigns values to a RaycastHit. Here it fills a data reference if that object is meant to receive news for any valid reasons.

Comment: so what kind of List do you think that they actually use? Simple array? Or List Generic etc.

Comment: Ahhh .. so that's the answer.  Thanks for this. The little devils do indeed do this at the level of creating components.  Bastards!  Why can't we have access to that!  I wish they hadn't used the `Interface` syntax from c# ........ because it really has nothing to do with Interfaces.  (it's the "opposite of" interfaces.)

Comment: Again, my assumption is that a Scene object has containers for each method. Most likely lists, since you need to add and remove while an object is created/destroyed. Also, Start is called on first run and never again. So it needs to be stored until proper time. Awake is called on construction.

Comment: @JoeBlow, I would think the process is different with interfaces, I would assume (again...) that it goes through a more "basic" process, as I mentioned. It could be that the constructor checks for interface implementation, adds the method to a container and that container checks for nullity in the case the component has been removed. That container is within MonoBehaviour too, like any MonoBahviour callbacks.

Comment: So the Unity engine is designed to circumvent ordinary C# behavior? The magic is done by manipulating either the CIL or the machine code rather than C# directly?

Comment: If I remember right, the magic is done by simply scanning the scripts (basic string search) before compilation so the compiler can mark that class with an implementation for a given method. Maybe as an attribute or manifest so that next time you create an instance, the attribute tells all the methods the object is implementing. Nothing new if you consider the assembly manifest in .NET, it already tells all you need to know about a class.

Comment: @KyleDelaney - yes, that is 10000% correct.  it kind of makes sense because at root, Unity / game engines have nothing to do with object oriented and normal software, they are a frame based system.  Anyone who works with Unity has given up on wondering of any kind of logic at Unity  :)  the thing is just to know what the hell is happening  :)

Comment: Unity is not a c# game engine. Unity is a cpp game engine but you write your code in c#. So, all those methods are invoked by cpp scripting runtime by unity. nothing like system.reflections etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can use reflection to get all types in an assembly that implements a specific interface and then instantiate those types and call the methods on those instances through the interface.

```
var types = this.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
                                   .Where(t=>t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IGetNews)));
foreach (var type  in types)
{
    var instance = (IGetNews) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    instance.SomeNews("news");
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks:  however .. consider, as I mention *"... it even works if you suddenly add one of these at run time, during a game. So, once the scene is already running, Instantiate a new GameObject, and add a component such as Whoa above - it will work from that frame onwards!"*  Surely Unity do not do the reflection every engine frame??  Do you think it's really just deep annoying trickery that we would not be able to do?  ie they follow components being created, or something?  :O  Or am I over-estimating, indeed is it perhaps trivial to do a reflection like that every frame?  thx  :/

Comment: link posted by @fafase 's answer shows that Unity doesn't use Assembly scanning for this

Comment: You would not need the reflection process for each frame, instead you would check on Awake and then add the found method to a container on a manager object. It gets a bit more cumbersome and less straight-forward to use in this case I would think. Also, it requires the addition of a manager, which is actually what Unity does for all MonoBehaviour callbacks.

Comment: HI fafase, nah you have to do it **every frame** if you want to simulate what unity does, using reflection as Mark explains.  The components in question could be created/destroyed at any moment in the game  :/  (unless I misunderstand you somehow)