# Why doesn't the access modifier matter in unity3D

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

Unity has a set of methods that you can use to implement behavior like `Start, Awake, Update` this methods have no access modifier which means that they are private in C# classes.

From what I know there's no way in C# to call a private method of another class without using reflection.

```
public class TestClass : MonoBehaviour {
    private void Start () {
       // How is unity able to call this method if it's private and I'm not calling it anywhere
    }

    void Update () {    
    }
}
```

So my question is how is unity able to call them if they are private? And why aren't they just `protected virtual` so you can use `override` ?

Comment: Does [this blog post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/) answer your question?

Comment: @mjwills I do agree that this applies to 90% of the cases, but in this case I think it makes no difference, I added it though.

Comment: @Milster really great blog post I was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Actually this was already asked a while ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251078/in-unity-how-does-unity-magically-call-all-interfaces/36251209#36251209

Comment: @Everts I'll have a look at the other question in a couple of hours and if it really is I'll mark it as a duplicate

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate. It is formulated differently but the result is basically the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unity itself is written in C++ and uses C# only for user-created scripts. Somewhere in documentation there is mentioned that all this "magic" methods (like `Start()`, `Update()` etc are called from C++ side by registering scripts which have this "magic" methods. For this methods it doesn't matter which access modified you use public or protected they will be called anyway.

As for why those methods are not protected virtual I can say that less of this methods you have - the better performance you get. If script doesn't have an `Update()` method, Unity doesn't have to register this script inside it's scripting system and doesn't have to call it each frame.

MonoBehaviour-derived script have huge overhead in compare of regular C# classes. This is because Unity have to manage all resources (graphics, gameObjects, physics, etc) itself except C# memory (it uses mono garbage collection for this purpose). So it's a good practice to use as less MonoBahaviour-derived classes as possible prefering regular C# classes.

Update: [here](https://blogs.unity3d.com/en/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/) is a good explanation from comments.