# Guard against object in deleted state inside delegate callback

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine, delegates

I'm writing a game in Unity3D, and I'm wondering if I should be using events -- or some other construct entirely -- instead of delegates for my web requests.

At certain points in the game's lifecycle, we need to call out to a REST API and await its response. Consider a UI screen that retrieves a list of your friends, and displays the number of friends, along with an entry for each friend. Currently, the workflow looks something like this, using `Action` delegates as parameters to the various methods of my `Server` class:

```
class FriendsUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Text friendCount; // A Unity Text component

    private void OnStart()
    {
        Server.GetFriends(player, response => {
            ShowFriendList(response.friends);
        });
    }

    private void ShowFriendList(List<Friend> friends)
    {
        this.friendCount.text = friends.Count.ToString();
        // Display friend entries...
    }
}
```

The `Server.GetFriends` method does an HTTP request to our REST API, gets the response, and calls the delegate, returning the response and control to `FriendsUI`.

This usually works just fine. However, if I closed the friends UI screen before the delegate is called, the `friendCount` component -- and any other component in the class, for that matter -- has been destroyed, and an NPE is thrown trying to access it.

Knowing that, do you think C#'s event system be a better design for this? `Server` would expose something like a `FriendsEvent` event, and `FriendsUI` would subscribe to it. At the point when `Server` has validated/transformed the response, it would raise the event. `FriendsUI` would also clean up after itself and unregister the handler when the GameObject on which the script has been attached is destroyed/disabled. That way, at the point the event is raised in `Server`, if the event handler is no longer valid in `FriendsUI`, it just wouldn't get called.

I'm just trying to run this through in my head before implementing it, because it would end up becoming a somewhat large refactor. I'm looking for guidance as to whether or not people think it's a good route to go, if there are any other routes that might turn out better, and any pitfalls I might run into along the way.

Thanks, as ever, for your time.

Comment: learn to use UnityEvent.  it couldn't be easier.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36249404/294884

Comment: Thanks for the info, Joe. The UnityEvent system seems a tad overly verbose, but it's probably the way to go. For example, the way I'm thinking about it, I need to expose a `FriendsResponseEvent` class in my `Server` class that extends `UnityEvent<FriendsResponse>`. I also need to declare and instantiate a `FriendsResponseEvent` property in `Server`. Then I add `Server.FriendsResponseEvent.AddListener(ReceivedFriends)` to my `FriendsUI#OnStart` method. That pattern needs to happen for every event `Server` wants to raise, which gets pretty wordy. Or maybe there's a more concise way?

Comment: As a test do this: (1) type `public UnityEvent teste;` in your server class. (2) somewhere in that class (example, once the connection is complete) go `teste.Invoke()`.  Finally (3) LOOK at the Inspector for your server class.  Now DRAG anything you want to "teste" (connect as many as you want that way).

Comment: never use "AddListener" there is no need for it.

Comment: I disagree about the use of `AddListener`. In my opinion, there is absolutely a need for it, when developers want to hook up listeners via code. I am much more comfortable doing that than hooking them up via the inspector. I'm happy to let a game designer wire up certain events through the inspector, but this use case is something the developers need to manage, and code is our preferred channel for doing that. The inspector might be OK if this was a one-developer operation, but that's not the case here. Either way, I'll keep looking at `UnityEvent` as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use C# `delegate` and `event`. Make each script that wants to be notified when friends list is received from the server to subscribe to the event.

```
public class FRIENDSAPI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void friendListReceived(List<FRINDSINFO> _friends);
    public static event friendListReceived onFriendListReceived;

    //Function that gets friends from the network and notify subscribed functions with results
    public void getFriends()
    {
      StartCoroutine(getFriendsCoroutine());
    }

    private IEnumerator getFriendsCoroutine()
    {
     List<FRINDSINFO> friendsFromNetwork = new List<FRINDSINFO>();

     /*
     NETWORK CODE

     //FILL friendsFromNetwork with Result
     friendsFromNetwork.Add();

     */


     //Make sure a function is subscribed then Notify every subscribed function
      if (onFriendListReceived != null)
      {
        onFriendListReceived(friendsFromNetwork);
      }

     yield return null;
     }
}
```

Then in your `FriendsUI` class, subscribe in the `Start()` function and unsubscribe in the `OnDisable()` function. You usually subscribe in the `OnEnable()` function but sometimes it doesn't work because things don't **initialize** on time. Doing it in the `Start()` function is a **fix** for that.

```
public class FriendsUI: MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
        //Subscribe
        FRIENDSAPI.onFriendListReceived += onFriendsReceived;

        FRIENDSAPI friendAPI = gameObject.GetComponent<FRIENDSAPI>();
        friendAPI.getFriends(); //Get friends
    }

    public void OnDisable()
    {
        //Un-Subscribe
        FRIENDSAPI.onFriendListReceived -= onFriendsReceived;
    }

    //Call back function when friends are received
    void onFriendsReceived(List<FRINDSINFO> _friends)
    {
        //Do Whatever you want with the result here(Display on the Screen)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It looks like this would be the route I'd go, if I were to use events ultimately. The main thing I wanted to run by people, however, was if events were the approach they thought was best for this type of scenario, or if there's a way to achieve it with delegates (i.e., modifying my current route) or if there's another approach that would suit  me better.

Comment: @Monkey34 You can use `Action` or do it your own way but the important thing for you to do is to make sure that you unsubscribe each time the subscribed class is destroyed/disabled. Failure to do so will introduce another problem.