# Unity 2D - Why does button not work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**OP figured it out, was missing `EventSystem` object**

I made a running game by Unity. But I faced a big problem. I made one button to jump and add onclick event, however, It is not working. My Runner doesn't jump on ground. Please Help me!

[image]

Button and Button Inspector.

[image]

Runner Inspector.

[image]

OnClick Inspector.

And This is a Runner's C# Script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class CsRunner : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Vector2 jumpVelocity;
        public Text _coin;
        int coinCount = 0, heartCount, healthCount = 0, grimReaperCount = 0, coupleCount = 0;
        bool isJump;
        public Button _jump;

        bool collision_box;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start()
        {
            _jump.onClick.AddListener(Jump);
            heartCount = 3;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            _coin.text = ""+coinCount;
        }

        void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
        {
            if (coll.transform.tag == "Enemy")
            {
                if (heartCount > 1)
                    Destroy(GameObject.Find("heart ("+(heartCount-1)+")"));

                else if (heartCount == 1)
                    Destroy(GameObject.Find("heart"));

                heartCount--;
            }

            if (coll.transform.tag == "HealthBuff")
            {
                Destroy(coll.gameObject);
                healthCount++;
            }

            if (coll.transform.tag == "GrimReaperBuff")
            {
                Destroy(coll.gameObject);
                grimReaperCount++;
            }

            if (coll.transform.tag == "CoupleBuff")
            {
                Destroy(coll.gameObject);
                coupleCount++;
            }

            if (coll.transform.tag == "FieldCoin")
            {
                Destroy(coll.gameObject);
                coinCount++;
            }
        }


        void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
        {
            if (coll.transform.tag == "Ground")
            {
                GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = true;
                collision_box = true;
                isJump = false;
            }
        }

        void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D coll)
        {
            if (coll.transform.tag == "Ground")
            {
                GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = true;
                collision_box = true;
                isJump = false;
            }
        }

        void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D coll)
        {
            if (coll.transform.tag == "Ground")
            {
                GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
                collision_box = false;
                isJump = true;
            }
        }

        public void Jump()
        {
            Debug.Log("JUMP!!");

            if (isJump)
            {
                isJump = false;
                transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpVelocity / 2, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            }

            if (collision_box)
            {
                isJump = true;
                transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpVelocity, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            }

            else
            {
                GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Run");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: "however, It is not working" - **WHAT** is not working ?

Comment: @Hellium I guess that the function is not firing.

Comment: Can you show us the OnClick part?

Comment: @Hellium When Button is click, My runner jump.

Comment: Is it possible that there is another RayCast target being hit first, like an overlaying panel or something similar?

Comment: @Diana : Is not that supposed to be the purpose of the button?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre I don't use RayCast.

Comment: @Diana although you may not use RayCast, the internal workings of unity use it by default for button click events in your UI, otherwise it would never know that you clicked it! Try setting the button's Z value to be higher than other UI object's

Comment: Did that work for you? :)

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre I change button's Z value -200, but It is same.

Comment: I solve the problem!! Canvas Object hasn't EventSystem!! Thank you everyone:)

Comment: Diana, if you add your own answer and mark it as the answer (think it takes 2 days after posting it), that'll save people from looking at the question. I did add at the top of your post that you solved it...

Comment: The title says "Unity 2D" but the question is tagged with "Unity3D"

Comment: Suggest you simply do this .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40554093/294884

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button \`OnSelect\` not functioning in Unity.UI Canvas situation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526504/button-onselect-not-functioning-in-unity-ui-canvas-situation)

Comment: hi @Amy - within Unity, it's totally normal to talk about "2D jobs" or "2D jobs".  No problem there.  (Just FTR, the product is actually called "Unity", NOT "Unity3D" as in the tag.)

Comment: @ChuckSavage Oh, I see.... I add answer. Thank you!

Comment: @JoeBlow Wow! I will reference it. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem!! Canvas Object hasn't EventSystem!! Thank you everyone:)

Comment: @swe She can't for 48 hours after posting the answer.