# Scriptable tiles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tile

I am trying to create a game using tilemap. Walls and background are not enough for me, what can I create using tiles. I need doors, coins and similar interactive tiles. That can perform actions and / or store information.

I created a script that extends tile. But then I could not find the tile I needed. Collision does not respond to them. It is impossible to get a specific tile from a tilemap and access the desired method.

How is it possible to implement it?

Clarification: i want to create an interactive tile like doors or bushes in pokemon red game

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[Tiles have a GameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tile-gameObject.html).

Assuming you're build something in 2D, you'll need to add a [`BoxCollider2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BoxCollider2D.html) component to it.

Then, if what you are dealing is an object that moves, you'll need to add as well a [`Rigidbody2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) component. If the object doesn't move at all, then mark it as static instead.

You can then track when the colliders interact with, for example, [`OnCollisionEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html).

Comment: Can I add components to the tile in inspector or something?

Comment: @Cixo you can to the GameObject

Comment: [Check this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60373506/5675325)

Comment: [Also relevant](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1714260/view.html)